# What's with the fugly red?

Tags: discussion, design

Maybe I'm simply not used to it, but a recent design update appears to have changed the background colour of popups such as the one below to a rather jarring, unwholesome red.

[image]

Do you find this choice of colour comfortable? Can something be done to tone it down a little?

Comment: It was hard to read the white message in the middle of a bloody sea! I suggest orange or light brown.

Comment: But I like this red! :)

Comment: I actually like this choice of colour.  Red is traditionally the colour of errors, and this one is not too vibrant.

Comment: I think a better fitting choice would be the texture/color of an old piece of tanned parchment. It gives the mind-set of "literature" and "language" being a classical thing that is studied mostly in books and lives on paper. (Of course this isn't the only case but it's kind of hard to come up with a style for "sound waves" isn't it? Haha.) http://www.google.com/search?q=old+parchment&tbm=isch

Answer (score 4):

I think small and crimson is far better than big and bright yellow. However I see no reason why each site's messages should not be tailored for the style sheet — why are our duplicate messages *blue*?